# Logistic Regression modeling in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

Consider this model:

$Y_i$ ~ Bernoulli($\pi_i$)

$X_i$ = 0,1

logit($\pi_i$) = $\lambda^{X_i}$ *  $\beta_0$

This model simplifies to logit($\pi_i$) = $\beta_0$ , when $x_i=0$ , and logit($\pi_i$) = $\lambda$*$\beta_0$ when $X_i$ = 1.

I am interested in testing the hypothesis $H_o$ : $\lambda$ =1, $H_a$ : $\lambda$ < 1 .

Could you please give me any hints to code this in R (using glm or any other package)?

Comment: It's a one-liner: use `prop.test`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have only two different categories ($X_i = 0$ or $1$), and you want to test whether the probability of the two groups are equal, you would can just a two sample test of proportion. If you want to test only $H_a: \lambda < 1$, this would be a one sided test.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response ! I want to know how to use glm (or any other package) to code this model in R as well. So finally, I would like to present 'lambda_hat' with corresponding 'p value' and 'beta0_hat' with corresponding 'p value'.